# trouble installing unknown apk on oreo

Tags: android, apk, android-8.0-oreo

I am trying to install an unknown apk on OREO. I configured the permissions to allow install of unknown apps in Chrome and File (I even allowed all the apps listed).

Then I downloaded the apk from Chrome, click Open. Instead of installing, it brings me to the app's folders without installing, no error messages.

Advice needed and thanks in advance.

Richard

Comment: what is the name of folder

Comment: i think they sent to archive folder, therefore it was not able to install. When i click open, it just shows the apk folders. Wait, .archivetemp....zip, zip file

Comment: can you please provide the link from where you are downloading APK

Comment: the apk is a private app. I am able to download it to other phones and get it installed. sorry. Could it be the app needs to be updated to be installed on Oreo? The app was created a few years ago.